# Green Function generating functional and Fourier transform spaces

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, path-integral, greens-functions, partition-function

I am given the transform of the generating functional for free Klein-Gordon theory,

$$Z[J]=N\int D\phi \, e^{i\int d^4 J(x)\phi(x)}\tilde{Z}[\phi]$$ where $\phi(x)$ is a scalar field. I'm a little confused on the meaning of the source density function $J(x)$; I know that it is an arbitrary function, but what I see in this transform is that I switch from the space of scalar fields to the one of the source. But then, I would go from a physical space to a non-physical one: what meaning does this have? Are they conjugated quantities just like position and momentum?

I fully understand conventional generating functionals.

Comment: Can you indicate in your question that you fully understand conventional generating functions, before moving on to QFT?

Comment: well, is it ok now?

Comment: OK, then just as *n* derivatives with respect to *x* of the [EGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_.28EGF.29) evaluated at *x* =0 yield the *n*th term of the sequence, generalization of *x* to an infinite dimensional vector *J* yields the *n*-point field moment [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(quantum_field_theory)#Uses) for the QFT when evaluated at *J* =0. Yes, fields and sources are generalized fourier conjugates.

Comment: Related [249307](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249307/physical-meaning-of-partition-function-in-qft).

Comment: Ok thank you very much :) but i still don't get why a physical quantity is conjugated to a non-physical one

Comment: It happens [all the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) to "physical" moments in probability theory, doesn't it? Have you taken statistical mechanics? *This* is what it runs on. "Physical" is a highly dangerous confusion-generating polemical adjective.