# What is the physical meaning of $W[J]=\frac{\hbar}{i}\ln Z[J]$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, vacuum, partition-function

The quantity $Z[J]$ (which is the generating functional for all Green functions) physically represents the probability amplitude for a system to remain in the vacuum state. Can we find a similar physical meaning of the quantity $$W[J]=\frac{\hbar}{i}\ln Z[J]$$ (which is the generating functional for all connected Green functions)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107049/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129080/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks. But both the question and the answers there are too heavy for me to understand at this moment.

Comment: It relaty boils down the fact that $\log a+\log b =\log (ab)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that, by definition,
$$
Z[J]=e^{-iW[J]}=\langle\Omega|e^{-iHT}|\Omega\rangle
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of your system, and $\Omega$ is the vacuum state. Therefore, $W[J]$ can be interpreted as the energy of the vacuum $E_\Omega$ in the presence of a source $J$, where the origin is chosen at $E=0$ for $J=0$. In other words, $W[J]$ is how much more energy does the vacuum have when we turn on an external source $J$.

More precisely, and as per $Z[J]=e^{-iW[J]}$, you can think of $W$ as the [Helmholtz free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy#Relating_free_energy_to_other_variables) of the system.

For more details, see e.g. ref.1., §11.3, or ref.2., §6.1.2 (and Appendix 18). See also [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249307/84967).

**References.**

1. Peskin & Schroesder - *An introduction To Quantum Field Theory*.
2. Zinn-Justin - *Quantum Field theory and Critical Phenomena*.

Comment: At a mathematical level, I understand what you said. Thanks. But even now, it is physically very abstract. I wonder if there is a way to understand this physically (in terms of a real quantum mechanical system coupled to a real source field)? Please forgive my English.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Sorry, but I haven't said anything mathematical, or at least I tried not to. Physically, $W[J]$ is the energy of the vacuum when you introduce a source $J$ in the system. I don't think one can by any more concrete than this...

Comment: I see. I thought I can think of the source as something like an external electric field or something and the $W[J]$ could be the energy in the presence and absence of that field. Thanks though. :-)

Comment: @mithusengupta123 That is absolutely right: the source $J$ could be an external electromagnetic field, or the current density of a fermion, or any other object that can couple to the system.